# java1.8_45 ThreadPoolExecutor use ArrayBlockingQueue occur deadlock

Tags: java, deadlock

[image: the threadpool corePoolSize = 128,maximumPoolSize=1280,workQueue is ArrayBlockingQueue,size 512]

Now, threadpool is full, workQueue is full, many thread blocking at workQueue's lock, and the consumer thread pool, all consumer thread, are waiting to take task.
I'm sure the ArrayBlockingQueue's lock can be acquire, but when released, head can't unpark,
[image: waitStatus != 0 unpark]

I don't know why, now the application is dead. If I send request to it, I just get this: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@2bfa7c15 rejected.

I must find out the reason.

Comment: You need to create a minimal reproducible example. How do you know threads are waiting to take a task? If the queue is not empty then they should get the task. Are you using synchronized somehow?

Comment: Are you aware that Java 8 update 45 is extremely old. Have you tried with a more recent version, like Java 8 update 352.